# Get Index of 1 item of string-arrays match index of another string arrays

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi im new in Android and i need some help

I have 2 Strings Arrays:

1 is `City Name`

2 is `City Code`

The Story is when ppl click on Autocomplete to choose City name then it will Toast City code,
I have used equals, `indexOf` but nothing work, can anyone tell me any solution?

Comment: a solution would be a composite object, City, containing a name and a postal code. being the same index is not always a guarantee that they are a match

Comment: Why don't you store your data into a HashMap structure so that any city name will have a unique city code?

Comment: Can you please post your code, so that it will be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom class with the override equal method

```
class City {
    private String name,pincode;

    public City(String name, String pincode) {
        this.name = name;
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }

    public String getPincode(){
        return pincode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof  String){
            return obj.equals(name);
        }else if(obj instanceof City){
            return name.equals(((City) obj).name);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Implement or use class like:

```
City obj[] = new City[10];
obj[0] = new City("abc","1233");
String pincode;
if(obj[0].equals("abc")) {
    pincode=obj[0].getPincode();
}
```

Comment: thank u sir, its work for me

Comment: cheers, Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Create class of City which will include both name and code. Create array of this City class and display only city name and on selection of that you'll get your code associate to that city too.

Answer (score 0):

this code may help you to solve to problem

```
public ArrayList<City> mListCity;
// add data in City list
if(mListCity != null && mListCity.size() > 0){
     mSPCity.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<City>(getActivity(), R.layout.dropdonw_listitem,mListCity));
}
        class City{
            public String mName;
            public String mCode;

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return mName;
            }
        }
```

get select items 
// display toast if(mSPCity.getSelectedItem() != null)  mSPCity.getSelectedItem().mName or mSPCity.getSelectedItem().mCode
implement the listener of spinner

```
mSPCity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                // your code
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
```